# Проверка на наличие детей определенного класса

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, блок

Есть блок

```html
<div>
  <div class="FilterDropdown__header FilterDropdown__header_opened FilterDropdown__selected">
    <div class="FilterDropdown__filter-open-group"><span class="FilterDropdown__header-title"><span class="FilterBlockNewDesign__title">Бренд</span></span><i class="FilterDropdown__toggle-opened arrow_01_B IconFontStory__icon IconFont IconFont_size_s IconFont_arrow_01_B"></i></div>
  </div>
  <div class="FilterDropdown__body FilterDropdown__body_opened" id="brandBody" style="height: 246px;">
    <div class="FilterGroupNewDesign">
      <div class="FilterGroupNewDesign__filter-item FilterLabelNewDesign">
        <div class="checkboxStyleDecoratorNewDesign checkboxStyleDecoratorNewDesign_size_m checkboxStyleDecoratorNewDesign_hoverable">
          <div class="FilterCheckbox FilterCheckbox_hoverable"><input type="checkbox" class="FilterCheckbox__input" name="8714_821acer"><span class="checkboxStyleDecoratorNewDesign__checkmark FilterCheckbox__checkmark"></span></div>
          <div class="checkboxStyleDecoratorNewDesign__title">
            <div class="FilterLabelNewDesign"><span class="FilterLabelNewDesign__name">ACER</span><sup class="FilterLabelNewDesign__counter">82</sup></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="FilterGroupNewDesign__filter-item FilterLabelNewDesign">
        <div class="checkboxStyleDecoratorNewDesign checkboxStyleDecoratorNewDesign_size_m checkboxStyleDecoratorNewDesign_hoverable">
          <div class="FilterCheckbox FilterCheckbox_hoverable"><input type="checkbox" class="FilterCheckbox__input" name="8714_821apple"><span class="checkboxStyleDecoratorNewDesign__checkmark FilterCheckbox__checkmark"></span></div>
          <div class="checkboxStyleDecoratorNewDesign__title">
            <div class="FilterLabelNewDesign"><span class="FilterLabelNewDesign__name">APPLE</span><sup class="FilterLabelNewDesign__counter">34</sup></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="FilterGroupNewDesign__filter-item FilterLabelNewDesign">
        <div class="checkboxStyleDecoratorNewDesign checkboxStyleDecoratorNewDesign_size_m checkboxStyleDecoratorNewDesign_hoverable">
          <div class="FilterCheckbox FilterCheckbox_hoverable"><input type="checkbox" class="FilterCheckbox__input" name="8714_821asus"><span class="checkboxStyleDecoratorNewDesign__checkmark FilterCheckbox__checkmark"></span></div>
          <div class="checkboxStyleDecoratorNewDesign__title">
            <div class="FilterLabelNewDesign"><span class="FilterLabelNewDesign__name">ASUS</span><sup class="FilterLabelNewDesign__counter">75</sup></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="FilterGroupNewDesign__filter-item FilterLabelNewDesign">
        <div class="checkboxStyleDecoratorNewDesign checkboxStyleDecoratorNewDesign_size_m checkboxStyleDecoratorNewDesign_hoverable">
          <div class="FilterCheckbox FilterCheckbox_hoverable"><input type="checkbox" class="FilterCheckbox__input" name="8714_821dell"><span class="checkboxStyleDecoratorNewDesign__checkmark FilterCheckbox__checkmark"></span></div>
          <div class="checkboxStyleDecoratorNewDesign__title">
            <div class="FilterLabelNewDesign"><span class="FilterLabelNewDesign__name">DELL</span><sup class="FilterLabelNewDesign__counter">47</sup></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="FilterGroupNewDesign__filter-item FilterLabelNewDesign">
        <div class="checkboxStyleDecoratorNewDesign checkboxStyleDecoratorNewDesign_size_m checkboxStyleDecoratorNewDesign_hoverable">
          <div class="FilterCheckbox FilterCheckbox_hoverable"><input type="checkbox" class="FilterCheckbox__input" name="8714_821hp"><span class="checkboxStyleDecoratorNewDesign__checkmark FilterCheckbox__checkmark"></span></div>
          <div class="checkboxStyleDecoratorNewDesign__title">
            <div class="FilterLabelNewDesign"><span class="FilterLabelNewDesign__name">HP</span><sup class="FilterLabelNewDesign__counter">82</sup></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="FilterGroupNewDesign__filter-item FilterLabelNewDesign">
        <div class="checkboxStyleDecoratorNewDesign checkboxStyleDecoratorNewDesign_size_m checkboxStyleDecoratorNewDesign_hoverable">
          <div class="FilterCheckbox FilterCheckbox_hoverable"><input type="checkbox" class="FilterCheckbox__input" name="8714_821iru"><span class="checkboxStyleDecoratorNewDesign__checkmark FilterCheckbox__checkmark"></span></div>
          <div class="checkboxStyleDecoratorNewDesign__title">
            <div class="FilterLabelNewDesign"><span class="FilterLabelNewDesign__name">IRU</span><sup class="FilterLabelNewDesign__counter">32</sup></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="FilterGroupNewDesign__filter-item FilterLabelNewDesign">
        <div class="checkboxStyleDecoratorNewDesign checkboxStyleDecoratorNewDesign_size_m checkboxStyleDecoratorNewDesign_hoverable">
          <div class="FilterCheckbox FilterCheckbox_hoverable"><input type="checkbox" class="FilterCheckbox__input" name="8714_821lenovo"><span class="checkboxStyleDecoratorNewDesign__checkmark FilterCheckbox__checkmark"></span></div>
          <div class="checkboxStyleDecoratorNewDesign__title">
            <div class="FilterLabelNewDesign"><span class="FilterLabelNewDesign__name">LENOVO</span><sup class="FilterLabelNewDesign__counter">78</sup></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="FilterGroupNewDesign__filter-item FilterLabelNewDesign">
        <div class="checkboxStyleDecoratorNewDesign checkboxStyleDecoratorNewDesign_size_m checkboxStyleDecoratorNewDesign_hoverable">
          <div class="FilterCheckbox FilterCheckbox_hoverable"><input type="checkbox" class="FilterCheckbox__input" name="8714_821msi"><span class="checkboxStyleDecoratorNewDesign__checkmark FilterCheckbox__checkmark"></span></div>
          <div class="checkboxStyleDecoratorNewDesign__title">
            <div class="FilterLabelNewDesign"><span class="FilterLabelNewDesign__name">MSI</span><sup class="FilterLabelNewDesign__counter">16</sup></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div><button class="FilterGroupNewDesign__filter_show-all linkStyleDecorator linkStyleDecorator_size_s linkStyleDecorator_colored linkStyleDecorator_theme_blue Button" name="" type="submit" value="" tabindex="0"><span class="linkStyleDecorator__text linkStyleDecorator__text_border_none">Показать все</span></button></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Внутри него есть блок

```html
<div><button class="FilterGroupNewDesign__filter_show-all linkStyleDecorator linkStyleDecorator_size_s linkStyleDecorator_colored linkStyleDecorator_theme_blue Button" name="" type="submit" value="" tabindex="0"><span class="linkStyleDecorator__text linkStyleDecorator__text_border_none">Показать все</span></button></div>
```

Как определить, что блок `<div id="brandBody" class="FilterDropdown__body FilterDropdown__body__opened" style="height: 246px;"></div>` с классом `FilterDropdown__body__opened` содержит внутри дочерний блок с классом `.FilterGroupNewDesign__filter_show-all`

элемент

```
<button class="FilterGroupNewDesign__filter_show-all linkStyleDecorator linkStyleDecorator_size_s linkStyleDecorator_colored linkStyleDecorator_theme_blue Button" name="" type="submit" value="" tabindex="0"><span class="linkStyleDecorator__text linkStyleDecorator__text_border_none">Показать все</span></button>
```

Я сумел нагуглить [есть ли у элемента дети](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9+js&newwindow=1&source=hp&ei=mnBNYbMOh9-uBJ-kgNAP&iflsig=ALs-wAMAAAAAYU1-qoCCou5S_2AJntL5403XKjWh-u3S&oq=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%8F+%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYADIGCAAQFhAeOgsIABCABBCxAxCDAToRCC4QgAQQsQMQgwEQxwEQowI6BQgAEIAEOggIABCABBCxAzoQCAAQgAQQsQMQyQMQRhCAAjoFCAAQkgM6CwguEIAEEMcBEK8BOgUILhCABDoICAAQgAQQyQM6CQgAEMkDEBYQHlCzB1ilMmClRmgAcAB4AIABsQGIAaQRkgEEMTIuOZgBAKABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz). Но как проверить есть ли среди дочерних элементов элементы с определенным классом?

Answer (score 1):

Проверяем как в *CSS*. Если по такому пути найдено, то длина коллекции будет больше нуля.

```js
if ($('.FilterDropdown__body.FilterDropdown__body_opened .FilterGroupNewDesign__filter_show-all').length > 0)
  console.log('имеется')
else
  console.log('отсутствует')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>


  <div class="FilterDropdown__header FilterDropdown__header_opened FilterDropdown__selected">
    <div class="FilterDropdown__filter-open-group"><span class="FilterDropdown__header-title"><span class="FilterBlockNewDesign__title">Бренд</span></span><i class="FilterDropdown__toggle-opened arrow_01_B IconFontStory__icon IconFont IconFont_size_s IconFont_arrow_01_B"></i></div>
  </div>
  <div class="FilterDropdown__body FilterDropdown__body_opened" id="brandBody" style="height: 246px;">
    <div class="FilterGroupNewDesign"> </div>
    
    <div>
        <button class="FilterGroupNewDesign__filter_show-all linkStyleDecorator linkStyleDecorator_size_s linkStyleDecorator_colored linkStyleDecorator_theme_blue Button" name="" type="submit" value="" tabindex="0"><span class="linkStyleDecorator__text linkStyleDecorator__text_border_none">Показать все</span>
        </button>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```